# Uso de "promedio" como adjetivo

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Existe la palabra *promedio* como adjetivo? EL sitio de DRAE dice que esta palabra
no está registrada. (Lo irónico es que Google Translate y mi otro diccionario de Español-Inglés la registran, pero como sustantivo.)  Encontré la frase *las diferencias promedio* y no sé si es correcta.

---

Does the word *promedio* exist as an adjective? The DRAE site says that this word is not registered in its records. (The strange thing is that Google Translate and my other Spanish-English dictionary can find it, but as a noun.) I stumbled on the phrase *las diferencias promedio* and I am not sure if it can be used to describe diferencias.

Comment: No es cierto que "promedio" no esté registrada en el DRAE; he aquí el enlace a la entrada: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=promedio

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Esta frase es de un documento sobre la educación estadística. La palabra "promedio" es usada con una definición matemática.

Comment: Ya. Pero, ¿puedes dar un poco más del contexto? Lo que has puesto no es la frase completa; tenerla completa ayudaría a entender mejor el contexto para sugerir una posible alternativa (aunque como dije en mi respuesta, así como está se suele usar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Promedio` es un sustantivo (si fuera adjetivo, debería concordar con el sustantivo que modifica). Su función en el ejemplo es de aposición especificativa.

> El sustantivo en *aposición **especificativa*** dice algo del sustantivo que le precede, algo que no está implícito en él, y que por eso lo define y distingue de los demás: *el coche cama* se distingue de otros coches que no tienen esta función.

De http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Aposiciones%20e%20incisos.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Promedio is a noun.**

I believe the confusion resides in that sometimes two nouns can be combined to express another meaning, like:

> El documento base / The base document

`Documento` and `base`, both are nouns, but together express the idea of an special document.

Comment: This was better explained in the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

It exists, before *explaining* my question I ***dare*** to say that DRAE is way of old fashioned about language customs.

*Promedio* is supposed to be a noun, but it's got this adjective meaning just as in english.

So, for:

> "Las diferencias promedio."

It means something like "the usual differences.

Comment: By the way, are you an english speaker?

Comment: So shouldn't it be 'promedias' instead?

Comment: Do you think I am an English speaker? :p

Comment: Please, could you please add to your answer some source supporting the claim that *promedio* can be used as adjective?

Comment: If it were an adjective, it would be "promedias". You are using "promedio" as a substantive.