# Can possession in Spanish be formed by two nouns placed in juxtaposition?

Tags: gramática

I'm confused by this excerpt from *Historia de una gaviota y del
gato que le enseñó a volar* by Luis Sepúlveda. It almost looks like an English possessive construction "the gaviotas' pilot":

> Llevaban seis horas de vuelo sin interrupciones y, aunque **las gaviotas
>   piloto** las habían conducido por corrientes de aires cálidos que
>   hicieron placentero el planear sobre el océano, sentían la necesidad
>   de reponer fuerzas, y qué mejor para ello que un buen atracón de
>   arenques.

Comment: Look at this question and its answer: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4155/uso-de-promedio-como-adjetivo . _Piloto_ is a “specifying apposition”, it distinguishes or specifies the preceding noun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T0pFGII):

> 6. m. U. en aposición, indica que la cosa designada por el nombre que le precede funciona como modelo o con carácter experimental. Piso, instituto piloto.

So it is a noun used in apposition (in English presumably = pilot gulls). There are also *ballenas piloto* for example (in English pilot whale).

Note in an [answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/4158/1674) angus provided a helpful link that provides a wealth of material on this topic:

http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Aposiciones%20e%20incisos.htm

Comment: I see, the noun is Gaviotas as indicated by the plural verb, and piloto functions like an invariable adjective. I'll bet there're very specific and defined rules to apposition like in German, but I haven't encountered them yet in spanish.